# How to display a data parsed from csv file through a link using Python

Tags: python, parsing, url, csv, encode

I read a csv file from  a link :

csv file format looks like this when I open it on text editor.

```
name, id, age, city
,steve, 1, 34, NY
,Rob, 2, 29, NY
,Ashly, 3, 28, NY
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

url = 'http://domainname.com/file.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
output   = StringIO.StringIO(response)

cr       = csv.reader((line.replace('NUL','') for line in output), delimiter=",")
```

when I iterate over the cr using

```
for row in cr:
    print row
```

I get this output which is diferent than the actual file data.

```
['\x1b']
['^']
['\xd3']
['\xd4']
['\xe7']
['\x88']
['\xf7']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code with a csv file from link mentioned below and everything is working perfectly fine. All the rows are printing correctly that means csv file is correctly received from url.

```
import urllib2
import StringIO
import csv


url = "http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.csv"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
output   = StringIO.StringIO(response)

cr       = csv.reader((line.replace('NUL','') for line in output), delimiter=",")

for row in cr:
        print row
```